# PHPSpreadsheet - Keeping Images/Drawings in row when sorting?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

**Background:**

I'm successfully inserting rows of data into a spreadsheet using the following to add text data:

```
$sheet->fromArray($user, NULL, 'B' . $counter);
```

And the following to add an image to the beggining of that row:

```
$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing->setName('Avatar');
$drawing->setDescription('Avatar');
$drawing->setPath('image.jpg');
$drawing->setCoordinates('A' . $counter);
$drawing->setWidthAndHeight(50, 50);

$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
```

This works fine

**Problem:**

When I then go to **sort** that data, the data is sorted successfully, but the images stay in their original place.

**Question:**

How can I ensure when the spreadsheet is sorted, the images move with the row as well?

Comment: How/where are you sorting the data? If in Excel itself there are of course options to have the entire row moved based on the sorting. If you are trying to do it with PHP sort your data the way you want it before creating the new spreadsheet.

Comment: I'm sorting in Google Sheets & Libra Office, both which by default don't sort the entire row. I'm looking for a way to essentially lock all columns in the row so that it works regardless of the program used

Comment: I do not see that behavior with Google Sheets. When a column is sorted the row data sorts with it. Regardless, this isn't really a question about PHP or phpspreadsheet at all. You COULD sort it before the spreadsheet is corrected as I suggested above.